# SharePoint 2013 - Open upload document window from a custom location/hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to create a hyperlink that will open the upload document window in SharePoint 2013?

I seen the following solution for sharepoint 2010 - but this doesn't seem to work in SP2013.

http://intapoint.com/2013/05/add-an-add-document-link-to-a-page-in-sharepoint-2010/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have Web app server installed, you can see the URL when you press the three dots.